# In R: How to generate a subset of a data table based on its common elements with two lists of characters

Tags: r, filter, datatable, dplyr, subset

I got stuck into this problem and I'm not sure what approach is more efficient!
I want to generate a data table based on two lists of characters:
My first data.table is:

```
sample 1   sample 2     N
   a         b          2
   c         c          1
   b         c          3
   c         d          2
   a         c          3
   d         f          1
   d         h          3
```

if the lists are :

```
List1= list('a','b')
List2= list('c')
```

Now, I want to look at the **"sample1"** and find the subset of the above data table based on the two lists.

The result that I am looking for is:

```
    sample 1   sample 2     N
   a         b              2
   c         c              1
   b         c              3
   c         d              2       
   a         c              3
```

I'd appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: The `[]` is not a R list..  Did you meant `List1 = list('a', 'b')` or `List1 = c('a', 'b')`

Comment: My bad, List 1 = list('a', 'b')

Comment: Please format your code.  It should be `list('a', 'b')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df2, sample1 %in% unlist(c(List1, List2)))
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(sample1 = c("a", "c", "b", "c", "a", "d", "d"), 
sample2 = c("b", "c", "c", "d", "c", "f", "h"), N = c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

List1 <- list('a', 'b')
List2 <- list('c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything keeping you from combining the lists and then filtering by the result?

For example:

```
list <- c(unlist(List1), unlist(List2))
df <- filter(df, `sample 1` %in% list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DT[`sample 1` %in% unlist(list(List1, List2))]
   sample 1 sample 2 N
1:        a        b 2
2:        c        c 1
3:        b        c 3
4:        c        d 2
5:        a        c 3
```

*Data*

```
List1 = list('a', 'b')
List2= list('c')
DT <- fread(
"sample 1,  sample 2,  N
 a,         b,          2
 c,         c,          1
 b,         c,          3
 c,         d,          2
 a,         c,          3
 d,         f,          1
 d,         h,          3")
```